# Can write to all smb shares except root of mounted USB drive

Tags: linux, samba, network-share, file-sharing, ubuntu-20.04

I have a USB drive mounted to /media/usbdrive on my Ubuntu 20.04 box.  I can write files to any share except the root share.  Meaning, I have these shares set up in **smb.conf:**

```
[usb]
path = /media/usbdrive
valid users = @samba
force user = shareuser
writable = yes
read only = no
browseable = yes

[apps]
path = /media/usbdrive/Apps
valid users = @samba
force user = shareuser
writable = yes
read only = no
browseable = yes

[music]
path = /media/usbdrive/Music/MP3
valid users = @samba
force user = shareuser
writable = yes
read only = no
browseable = yes
```

From Windows 10 (192.168.0.229), I can access the shares by providing a password for `shareuser`.  Then I can write files to any directory in the `apps` and `music` shares, but not `usb` - I get an "access is denied" error.    The same directories that are inaccessible through `usb` can be written to when accessed through the `apps` and `music` shares.

Any ideas?  I've tried playing around with different owners for the /media/usbdrive directory but it doesn't seem to help (but maybe I'm missing something).

```
drwxrwxrwx+ 11 root samba 4096 Apr  9 12:07 usbdrive

$ sudo smbstatus

Samba version 4.11.6-Ubuntu
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3682    shareuser    shareuser    192.168.0.229 (ipv4:192.168.0.229:52277)  SMB3_11           -                    partial(AES-128-CMAC)

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
usb          3682    192.168.0.229 Sun May 10 02:19:18 PM 2020 PDT  -            -
apps         3682    192.168.0.229 Sun May 10 02:21:40 PM 2020 PDT  -            -
music        3682    192.168.0.229 Sun May 10 02:19:18 PM 2020 PDT  -            -

Locked files:
Pid          User(ID)   DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock           SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3682         1001       DENY_NONE  0x80        RDONLY     NONE             /media/usbdrive   .   Sun May 10 14:19:18 2020
3682         1001       DENY_NONE  0x80        RDONLY     NONE             /media/usbdrive/Music/MP3   .   Sun May 10 14:19:18 2020
3682         1001       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /media/usbdrive/Apps   .   Sun May 10 14:22:00 2020
3682         1001       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /media/usbdrive/Apps   .   Sun May 10 14:22:15 2020
3682         1001       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /media/usbdrive/Apps   .   Sun May 10 14:22:25 2020
```

Comment: What are the permissions and ownership on /media/usbdrive ?   I wonder if it chown shareuser /media/usbdrive is all thats required?

Comment: I changed it: drwxrwx---+ 11 shareuser samba 4096 Apr  9 12:07 usbdrive
And it still doesn't work.